# How can you get Smaato ads to open in system Browser when building mobile apps in Monaca?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, monaca, smaato

I've got a couple apps that I want to place ads in.  I've tried using a couple different ad platforms but have decided on Smaato (inmobi was my first choice, but I've not had any success with my getting account activated).  Smaato integrates well and it works, however it's js (hosted on their site) has the links opening with target="_blank".  This would be great if I was using this on a website instead of an app, however all this does on my app is open it in the inapp browser.  I tried downloading a local copy of the js and changing the function to build with target="_system" instead, but this breaks it somehow.

If anyone has done anything similar to this please let me know what you did to get it working.

Thank you

Comment: Hey Crash. 
Sohan from InMobi here. Do you need help getting your account activated? Not sure why that happened but I can take a look.

Comment: Hello Sohan.  My account is now activated, but I'm still having issues with the setup.  Whenever I try to add and verify a property it get's stuck in the "Approval Pending" status.  Every time I reach out for help with it, no one seems to be able to help me.  If you are able to help me get inmobi properly setup, I will gladly switch to it.

Comment: Can you give me the email ID associated with your InMobi login? I'll take a look.